# I don't understand why it doesn't let me check 'contains' on switch cases

Tags: swift

I was trying to do the following:

```
var stringwithcharactherTofind = "booboo$booboo"

switch stringwithcharactherTofind{
  case stringwithcharactherTofind.ifhasprefix("$"):
  stringwithcharactherTofind = "done"
  default:
  break
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

At all

Comment: There is no "contains" in your code. A method "ifhasprefix" does not exist. A switch statement is not an if statement.

Comment: do you know what would be the easiest way to do this using switch statemants

Comment: Why do you want a switch? What is wrong with `if s.hasPrefix("$")` or `if s.contains("$")` ?

Comment: because i want to stop the function from doing the other things

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41402770/2976878

Comment: @Hamish: Wow, I hadn't seen that!

Comment: @MartinR Hah, that's crazy :D

Comment: I have reopened the question because – as it turned out – OP was looking for the `case _ where ...` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch statement matches the given value against the given patterns.
`stringwithcharactherTofind.hasprefix("$")` is a boolean expression
and not a pattern that a string can be matched against.

You *could* (ab)use the `where` clause in combination with the
wildcard pattern:

```
let str = "FooBar"

switch str {
case _ where str.hasPrefix("Foo"):
    print("prefix")
case _ where str.contains("Foo"):
    print("contains")
default:
    print("nope")
}
```

You *could* even define a pattern match operator which allows to
match a value against a boolean predicate (also demonstrated
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41402868/1187415)):

```
func ~=<T>(lhs: (T) -> Bool, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs(rhs)
}

let str = "FooBar"

switch str {
case { $0.hasPrefix("Foo") }:
    print("prefix")
case { $0.contains("Foo") }:
    print("contains")
default:
    print("nope")
}
```

But why make it so complicated? A `if/else if/else` statement
does exactly what you need:

```
if str.hasPrefix("Foo") {
    print("prefix")
} else if str.contains("Foo") {
    print("contains")
} else {
    print("nope")
}
```

Comment: thx you very much, _ where is what i needed i tried using it earlier but didnt know i had to put _ before it